# need to connect to MQ7 using Host_name, Queue_name, channel_name and binding file

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, websphere-7, mq

I have details of Host_name, Queue_name, channel_name and binding file, Except Queue_manager name. and i need to connect to MQ 7. Please just give a connectivity program. I tried posting in this and other forums but the connection problem still persists. So i thought if anyone could help me with the code. I will be very happy if anyone help me to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know Host name, channel name and port number, then you can get the queue manager name like below:

```
 MQEnvironment.channel = 'SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN'; //Replace with your channel name
 MQEnvironment.hostname = 'localhost'; //Replace with your host name
 MQEnvironment.port = 1414; //Replace with your port number

 MQQueueManager QM_OBJ= new MQQueueManager("");

 String QueueManagerName = QM_OBJ.getAttributeString(MQC.MQCA_Q_MGR_NAME, 100).trim();
```

Comment: Thanks buddy.. Actually its working with MQ6. I am not able to test it with MQ7 as their is firewall issue. I will let you know in a week..